# Extracting symbols from string with regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a String in such format `${something}` and want to extract `something` using regular expressions in Java. Here is my code:

```
String tmp = null; 
Pattern pVars = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([^}]*)\\}");
Matcher mVars = pVars.matcher(vars[0]);
if (mVars.find())
{
         tmp = mVars.group();
}
```

But I get full String in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You are still extracting the whole pattern instead of the group inside parentheses. This is how `group` behaves when it has no parameters.

Specify the first capturing group by passing `1` as parameter:

```
tmp = mVars.group(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `group(1)` to access the inner group demarked by `()` in your expression.